# KAFKA consumer not reading message. Updating offsate.Console consumer is reading the msg

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I can see that the producer is putting the message in the topic.
I have KAFKA and Zookeeper in the same machine.

```
      Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerStreams =   CONSUMERCONNECTOR.createMessageStreams(topicCount);         
      // Get Kafka stream for topic 
      List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> kStreamList = consumerStreams.get(topic);
      // Iterate stream using ConsumerIterator
      String strMsg = new String();
      if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
          logger.debug(" \n start reading messages");
      }
      for (final KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> kStreams : kStreamList) {
          if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
              logger.debug(" \n in For loop. Size of streamlist: " + kStreamList.size());
          }

             ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> consumerIte = kStreams.iterator();
             if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                 logger.debug(" \n got iterator. Size: " + consumerIte.size());
             }
             while (consumerIte.hasNext()){
                 strMsg = new String(consumerIte.next().message());
                 logger.debug("Message consumed from topic    [" + topic + "] : "  + strMsg);
                 addToEventCollection(strMsg);
             }
      }
```

Comment: This looks like the old consumer api. What's the version of your Broker?

Comment: kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1. It has worked sometime. Currently I am hosting KAFKA and the  consumer service is AWS boxes.

Comment: The old high-level consumer still seems to be supported, so that should not be a problem. But I'm not familiar with it so I don't know what the problem is. If this is a new development I'd suggest the new consumer apis though.

Comment: I migrated to new API so it started working. Couldnt fine the problem with old APi though as that was intermittently working.  Thanks for your suggestion.